# Search and Replace within XML tag via sed over multiple lines

Tags: sed

i want to change the value of a specific XML tag property.

There are many questions about how to handle sed, but the problem here is the newline within the tag.

I want to change the value after `name=` and it must be searched in the `<package ... >` tag

XMLStarlet is not an option.

Coverage.xml

```
<package branch-rate="0.031746031746" complexity="0.0"
   line-rate="0.159420289855" name="include">
<classes>
    <class branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0"
```

My best try so far:

```
sed -n '/<package/ {
:a
n
/<classes>/q
s/name=/xxxx/g
}' coverage.xml
```

Do you have an idea?

**UPDATE 2: More of coverage.xml with approach of @RavinderSingh13**

```
<package branch-rate="0.031746031746" complexity="0.0"
   line-rate="0.159420289855" name="NEW_VALUE">
   <classes>
    <class branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0"
     filename="NEW_VALUE"
     name="NEW_VALUE">
```

Comment: *"XMLStarlet is not an option"*... okay, why not? And what *is* an option? Because `sed` is definitely not an option for this task. Python maybe? `xsltproc`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk`, then as per your shown samples could you please try following once.(this will look only for package tag and its name value and for rest tags it will not do anything)

```
awk '/^>/{flag=""}  /<package/{flag=1} flag && /name=/{sub(/name=.*\"/,"name=\"NEW_VALUE\"")} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it renames other variables in other tags too..

I updated the original post with your approach

Comment: @Velocity, could you please give example for it?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a little tweak using a for loop.

```
LINES=`awk '/<package /{print NR+1}' coverage.xml`

for i in ${LINES};
do 
echo $i
sed -i ''"${i}"'s/name=.*/name="NEW_VALUE"/' coverage.xml;
done
```

The `NR+1` helps to reach the second line in the package tag.

Comment: You need not to use these many commands for this requirement, if you could clarify your concern over my comments we could probably do it within single command.